# How to create a censor "translator" via function in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a "translator" of sorts, in which if the `raw_input` has any curses (pre-determined, I list maybe 6 test ones), the function will output a string with the curse as `****`.

This is my code below:

```
def censor(sequence):
    curse = ('badword1', 'badword2', 'badword3', 'badword4', 'badword5', 'badword6')
    nsequence = sequence.split()
    aword = '' 
    bsequence = []
    for x in range(0, len(nsequence)):
        if nsequence[x] != curse:
            bsequence.append(nsequence[x])
        else:
            bsequence.append('*' * (len(x)))
        latest = ''.join(bsequence)
        return bsequence



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(censor(raw_input("Your sentence here: ")))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to simply use Python's native string method: `str.replace`

```
def censor(string):
    curses = ('badword1', 'badword2', 'badword3', 'badword4', 'badword5', 'badword6')
    for curse in curses:
        string = string.replace(curse, '*' * len(curse))
    return string
```

To improve efficiency, you could try to compile the list of curses into a regular expression and then do a single replacement operation.

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace)

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no need to iterate over element indices here. Python allows you to iterate over the elements themselves, which is ideal for this case.

Second, you are checking whether each of those words in the given sentence is equal to *the entire `tuple` of potential bad words*. You want to check whether each word is *in* that `tuple` (a `set` would be better).

Third, you are mixing up indices and elements when you do `len(x)` - that assumes that `x` is the word itself, but it is actually the index, as you use elsewhere.

Fourth, you are joining the sequence within the loop, and on the empty string. You should join it on a space, and only after you've checked each element.

```
def censor(sequence):
    curse = {'badword1', 'badword2', 'badword3', 'badword4', 'badword5', 'badword6'}
    nsequence = sequence.split()
    bsequence = []
    for x in nsequence:
        if x not in curse:
            bsequence.append(x)
        else:
            bsequence.append('*' * (len(x)))
    return ' '.join(bsequence)
```